# Galilean invariance of Newton second law with potential force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, galilean-relativity

Let's consider particle in some potential $V(x)$. Newton law:

$$m \ddot x= -\partial _x V(x)$$

After Galilean transformation:

$$
x^\prime  = x -vt
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
t^\prime = t
$$

Form of equation must be the same:

$$m \ddot x^\prime= -\partial_{x^\prime} V(x^\prime)$$

From this we obtain:

$$m \ddot x= -\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^\prime}\partial_x V(x-vt) = -\partial_x V(x-vt)$$

But this equation different from Newton law in x coordinate. Where I did a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight mistake in your assumptions. Newton's second law is:
\begin{equation}
m \ddot x = - \partial_x \Phi(x;t).
\end{equation}
After Galilean transformations, you get
\begin{equation}
m \ddot x' = - \partial_{x'} \Phi(x' + v t; t) = - \partial_{x'} \Phi'(x'; t'),
\end{equation}
where $\Phi(x,t)$ changed becoming the new function $\Phi'(x',t')$, but the equations of motion are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there should be a time derivative in addition:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{'}} V(x^{'}) = 
\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial x^{'}} \right) \partial_t V(x^{'}) + 
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^{'}} \right) \partial_x V(x^{'}) = 
-\frac{1}{v} \partial_t V(x-vt) +  \partial_x V(x -vt)
$$

Comment: But you didn't solve problem